# Nullable Datetime in getset property

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

```
Sub Main()
    Dim e As Example = New Example()
    ' Set property.
    If Date.TryParse("Null", e.Number) Then
        'get the valid date
        '10/12/2016'
    Else
        'get the value as nothing
        'Nothing
    End If
    ' Get property.
    Console.WriteLine(e.Number)
    Console.ReadKey()
End Sub

Class Example
    Private _count As Date

    Public Property Number() As Date
        Get
            Return _count
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Date)
            _count = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

I want to get the correct date if the date is valid if else I need to store Nothing or null inside e.number 
Note:- I should get the value in e.number

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare your property as being nullable, which means using `Nullable(Of Date)` or the shorthand `Date?`.  You can then do this:

```
If Date.TryParse(myString, myDate) Then
    myObject.MyNullableDateProperty = myDate
Else
    myObject.MyNullableDateProperty = Nothing
End If
```

When it comes time to use a nullable value type, you must first use its `HasValue` property to determine whether there's a value to use, then get that value from its `Value` property, e.g.

```
If myObject.MyNullableDateProperty.HasValue Then
    Console.WriteLine("The date is " & myObject.MyNullableDateProperty.Value.ToString())
Else
    Console.WriteLine("There is no date")
End If
```